# Overriding admin views - Django

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-views

I am using `Django 1.3` and `python 2.7` .I am using Django admin app.What I want is when a `superuser` logs-in it should be shown admin/index.html  with all models which is default behaviour but if any other user logs-in that is not superuser then it should be shown a totally different template with my data (like 'abc.html').What should I do to accomplish this?I guess I need to override some admin view to do this but have no idea?

Please help.If you want more information plz comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a modified AdminSite class definition with additional permission rules.

```
class SuperUserAdminSite( AdminSite ):
    def has_permission(self, request):
        return request.user.is_active and request.user.is_staff and request.user. is_superuser
```

Now you can create two AdminSite objects, one for ordinary users, one for super users.

You can have two paths in your URLs for the two admin sites.

Superusers can use both paths.

Ordinary users will only be able to use the ordinary user path in the URL.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-objects

Answer (score 3):

I would create a middleware that checks if the user is a superuser or not. If the user is not supeuser you redirects him/her to the custom admin page instead of the default one.

```
class SuperUserMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        user = request.session.user
        if not user.is_superuser:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(NON_SUPERUSER_URL)
        ...
```

Comment: @anks this example is just from top of my head, nothing is tested.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the view of the admin site. Django Documentation mention all in detail. Please check that https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/ if you have any error then please write back with some code details.

Comment: That I know but which view login view?